Whats the suns resting point?
In Quran 36:38:And the sun runs [on course] toward its stopping point. That is the determination of the Exalted in Might, the Knowing.
some translations say resting point, what does this refer to? Is the stopping point or resting point when it sets?

That must have a metaphorical explanation, not a physical one. Or, maybe, "stopping point" is the point from where the sun does not rise further in the sky.
